# Swagger API on multiple OSGI bundle using Apache karaf

Tags: web-services, caching, osgi, cxf, swagger

I have created Java RESTFUL web services using Apache karaf, I am using swagger for API documentation.All Annotation are applied and its running successfully on single OSGI bundle with the general swagger configuration(Swagger core and annotation jar) with apache karaf on standalone mode.

**Issue** :-  While running swagger on multiple OSGI bundles, it is catching the result generated while hitting "/api-docs" on the very first WSDL and returns the same for other WSDL's as well.

**Description**:-

Let us consider if i have two web services exposed as below

1)  "http:/localhost:8181/cxf/abc?_wadl"

2) "http:/localhost:8181/cxf/xyz?_wadl"

Both the web services are exposed on two different OSGI bundles and all the configuration are written in respective "bluprint.xml" files.Swagger core and swagger-annotation dependencies are located in each project's pom.xml.

When i run swagger api on first WSDL ie "http:/localhost:8181/cxf/abc/api-docs"

it returns the result successfully but on hitting swagger on second WSDL ie.
"http:/localhost:8181/cxf/xyz/api-docs"

it returned the same result which was initially produced by the first WSDL. It cached the first WSDL json and always return the same(some where it cached my initial json result).

**My Questions**:-

1 - Is there any other way to run swagger API on Multiple OSGI bundles using Apache Karaf ?

2 - Is there any way, We can permanently disable the caching using karaf/swagger Configuration ?

3 - Is there any method to clear swagger cache( which got created when i made a hit to http:/localhost:8181/cxf/abc/api-docs) when hitting swagger for next OSGI bundles("http:/localhost:8181/cxf/xyz/api-docs"), So it rescans the API Annotations and does't return me the cached result.

**Note** : - i have implemented the swagger API on OSGI bundles using :- https://github.com/ddragosd/jax-rs-on-karaf

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run your service using CXF and the [CXF Swaggger feature](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using the same configuration in buleprint.xml for implementing swagger API .Could you please suggest me some other way to implement swagger API on multiple OSGI bundles.

Comment: So the CXF swagger feature does not work for more than one bundle? I would regards this as a bug. Can you open an issue at CXF for it?

Comment: I researched a bit more on this…
Please refer the below JIRA issue -
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6740

Please provide your suggestion.